# How to obtain all file names in a directory and write them into the html

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with a script that has dozens and dozens of lines like this...

```
<img class="mySlides" src="\Slides\Whatver.png" />
<img class="mySlides" src="\Slides\SomeFile.png" />
<img class="mySlides" src="\Slides\AnotherOne.png" />
```

The files change frequently and it's a hassle to maintain this code. How can I obtain a listing of that subdirectory (the "slides" are the only files there) and just write those lines of code using `document.write` when the page loads?

Yes I am a complete script newbie, please be gentle.

Comment: you'll need to do that in your server side code, because a browser does not have access to the server side folder contents - (it can, based on your http server settings, but let's just keep it simple for now and say it can't) - oh, and don't use `document.write`

Comment: What is the backend language you use? PHP?

Comment: PHP is available on the server.